# Does APK shared from web or xender gets update from playstore?

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, apk, google-apps-marketplace

Many websites providing apk of playstore's apps . and many apps like xender and myappsharer can transfer apk .

in both will they get updates from playstore ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. all app are downloaded from web can get update from google play store.
Download app from google play store and from the web all are same.
Just difference is you have to install it manually when you download apps and game from websites.